# Call a function into a export variable

Tags: angular, typescript, core-ui

I have a file with an export const what is used to build some navigation navbar from coreui, but I'm trying to find a way to build some dynamic json with data from in other Components or either the same file and inject into that exported const. Any ideas ?

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
export const navItems = [
  {
    name: 'Create Form',
    url: environment.URL,
    icon: 'icon-plus',
  },
  {
    name: 'Views',
    url: '#',
    icon: 'cil-applications',
     children: [
        //inject some dynamic json here from other function
     ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use InjectionToken to provide its value for your module.

You could create a interface for this object, then reference this variable in your module using:

```
const navItems: YourObjectInterface = {
  ...
}

export const NAV_ITEMS = new InjectionToken<YourObjectInterface>('nav.items');

...

providers: [{ provide: NAV_ITEMS, useValue: navItems }]
```

Then on your component you would inject it like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(NAV_ITEMS) items: YourObjectInterface) { }
```

For more info on dependency providers:

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers